# Кнопка перехода в почтовый аккаунт клиента

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать переход на страницу почтового клиента пользователя?

Реализована форма захвата, с которой пользователь переходит на страницу благодарности. На странице благодарности находится кнопка "**Проверить почту**", с последующим письмом о подтверждении регистрации. Как реализовать переход на почту,  чтобы человек нажал и перешел в свой почтовый лиент по умолчанию? Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Как получить адрес и название почты, используя адрес email, который сообщил вам пользователь? Ловите табличку в формате CSV:

```
"почтовый домен", "название почтового сервиса","адрес для входа в почту"
"mail.ru","Почта Mail.Ru","https://e.mail.ru/"
"bk.ru","Почта Mail.Ru (bk.ru)","https://e.mail.ru/"
"list.ru","Почта Mail.Ru (list.ru)","https://e.mail.ru/"
"inbox.ru","Почта Mail.Ru (inbox.ru)","https://e.mail.ru/"
"yandex.ru","Яндекс.Почта","https://mail.yandex.ru/"
"ya.ru","Яндекс.Почта","https://mail.yandex.ru/"
"yandex.ua","Яндекс.Почта","https://mail.yandex.ua/"
"yandex.by","Яндекс.Почта","https://mail.yandex.by/"
"yandex.kz","Яндекс.Почта","https://mail.yandex.kz/"
"yandex.com","Yandex.Mail","https://mail.yandex.com/"
"gmail.com","Gmail","https://mail.google.com/"
"googlemail.com","Gmail","https://mail.google.com/"
"outlook.com","Outlook.com","https://mail.live.com/"
"hotmail.com","Outlook.com (Hotmail)","https://mail.live.com/"
"live.ru","Outlook.com (live.ru)","https://mail.live.com/"
"live.com","Outlook.com (live.com)","https://mail.live.com/"
"me.com","iCloud Mail","https://www.icloud.com/"
"icloud.com","iCloud Mail","https://www.icloud.com/"
"rambler.ru","Рамблер-Почта","https://mail.rambler.ru/"
"yahoo.com","Yahoo! Mail","https://mail.yahoo.com/"
"ukr.net","Почта ukr.net","https://mail.ukr.net/"
"i.ua","Почта I.UA","http://mail.i.ua/"
"bigmir.net","Почта Bigmir.net","http://mail.bigmir.net/"
"tut.by","Почта tut.by","https://mail.tut.by/"
"inbox.lv","Inbox.lv","https://www.inbox.lv/"
"mail.kz","Почта mail.kz","http://mail.kz/"
```

Разумеется, это далеко не все почтовые службы. Рекомендую заглянуть в список почтовых адресов ваших пользователей и добавить именно те сервисы, которыми они пользуются.
Создать таблицу и импортировать CSV-файл в MySQL можно следующей командой:

```
CREATE TABLE email_services(domain CHAR(24) NOT NULL,name CHAR(32) NOT NULL,url CHAR(64) NOT NULL);
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/user/services.csv' INTO TABLE email_services FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';
```

А дальше вы просто выделяете из адреса *email* почтовый домен, по нему находите в таблице название и адрес почтового сервиса, и показываете их пользователю.

Вы можете написать название сервиса, можете просклонять названия и сделать красивую надпись *«Перейти в Яндекс.Почт**у**»* или просто показать сам email. Главное, чтобы там была ссылка на его «Входящие».

[источник](https://habrahabr.ru/post/245595/)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/74207)

Comment: @ThisMan спасибо! Уже поправил. Хотя у меня возникают сомнения с тем, что Источник будет менять ссылку, но все же.

Comment: Спасибо за решение. Однако я не указал, что у нас обычные лендинги а не сайты с движками. Ест ьли решение в виде скрипта на js для одностраничника?

Comment: @Zerkella простите, но я не особо специалист в js. Поделился только тем, с чем реально имел дело. Хотя, думаю, если загнать это все в какой-то контейнер в самом **js**'е, то все может заработать

Comment: Благодарю за помощь